# Bash script for looping through a program for several different input files

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I would like a bash script to run a program (taking several variables and an input file) in the background, but I want the script to only process one input file (all input files in one directory) at a time. e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh  
for file in *  
do  
    ~/FrameDP/bin/FrameDP.pl --cfg ~/FrameDP/cfg/FrameDP.cfg --no_train --infile /home/bop08olp/FrameDP/data/"$file" --outdir ~/FrameDP/test  
done
```

I'm guessing the above script is not going to wait between each processing of separate input files, but will just start them all at once. The program generates lots of child processes. Any pointers appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in that code implies that it won't wait for completion.

Comment: This looks like [this package](http://iant.toulouse.inra.fr/FrameDP/ "FrameDP: sensitive peptide detection on noisy matured sequences"), which appears to already do parallel processing.  I think we need to know more details to know exactly what the problem is, though; the stock `FrameDP.pl` doesn't appear to background itself.

Comment: Yes, it is that package, and it does do parallel processing, but on one input file. I want to run the whole thing sequentially on several input files. That is, just leave it to churn through an input file, produce outputs, and then take the next input file in the folder and start over again.  Can I background it just by adding an ampersand at the end of the stock line?

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. I didn't try it because I was already in the process of running the program (which was taking up all the cpus). I was just assuming that it wouldn't wait for completion based on reseaching the problem online. But I'll try it out when my machine has finished the current job.

Comment: Tried out the script as it is, and it just loops through and takes every file, starting a new process for each one at the same time. Any help to get it to wait for each job to complete before starting with a new input file would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it does work sequentially; my bad. When I tried it first I had an ampersand at the end of the program-call line. I now understand that by backgrounding the processes the script does not wait for them to finish before proceeding with the loop. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sh loops are not parallelized, you can verify it by running :

```
for i in *
    sleep 1
done
```

And you'll see that if you have > 1 file that the total time is > than 1s but equal to 'number of files' seconds.

So if actually running the code snippet you gave ran all the process in the same time, it's because of your perl script have a feature to run in the background, you should review your perl script, not your shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am thinking too simple and I am too late, but what about

```
find . -depth 1 -exec ~/FrameDP/bin/FrameDP.pl --cfg ~/FrameDP/cfg/FrameDP.cfg --no_train --infile /home/bop08olp/FrameDP/data/{} --outdir ~/FrameDP/test \; &
```

where {} takes the place of the former variable $file and "\;" is find's demanded sequence to denote the end of the exec clause?